# Dart Data Class Generator is not working it is showing: item couldn't be converted to a data class: Class doesn't have unique property names

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio, vscode-extensions

[[image: the code][1]][image: the extension I the errordownloaded]

Dart Data Class Generator is not working it is showing: item couldn't be converted to a data class: Class doesn't have unique property names

Comment: Have you tried putting each class on its own file

Comment: Please add code not as screenshot but as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am having the same issue (it used to work)..

import 'dart:convert';

import 'model_exports.dart';

class FIDS_FlightUpdate {

```
GreatCircleDistance? greatCircleDistance ;
DepartingDepartureInfo?  departure;
DepartingArrivalInfo?    arrival;

String? lastUpdatedTimeUtc ; //Example:"2021-10-04 18:20Z"
String? number;  //Example:"AF 3139"
String? callSign;
String? status;  //Example:"Departed"
String? codeshareStatus;  //example:"IsCodeshared"
bool?   isCargo;  //Example:false
FIDS_Aircraft? aircraft;
FIDS_Airline? airline;
```

}
Gives error message......
FIDS_FlightUpdate couldn't be converted to a data class: Class doesn't have unique property names!

I do not see any duplicate property names.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have two models in the same dart file. Start by separating them into their respective dart files.

For each model u want to use the generator on, make sure you have defined their properties before applying the generator using short-cut key combination:

> Ctrl + Shift + P

and type Dart Data class Generator: Generate from class properties and strike enter key.

**Make sure you don't have duplicate properties.**

with the above done, it should work fine. However, if it doesn't, please post here with more details about the error.